# If gravity is fictitious force why we search for gravitons?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, equivalence-principle, carrier-particles

If gravity is fictitious force why we even search for gravitons?

I mean, centrifugal or coriolis force don't have carriers, because these forces dont exist.

Comment: See previously asked question, and answers: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5072/

Comment: Who upvoted this?

Comment: A question being a duplicate doesn't mean mean it's a bad question... If you don't go searching for duplicates, it looks like a good question.

Comment: A reminder to all users, voting on SE is confidential.  It's considered poor behavior to ask who voted or what way someone voted.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine Have you ever heard of a rhetorical question?